# Using a users github account to authenticate their identity to login in and access our website

Tags: authentication, github, github-api

I am building a website that has a list of quizzes to help new developers learn to program.

I would like the login page to use the users github account to authenticate their identity and be connected to the website.

Example: top scores page shows link to github.

Can this be done using a github api? and can someone point in the right direction towards documentation to get me started?

Please be kind.
Thank you!

Comment: [This](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/) might help.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, there is a way.**
Github has API for OAUTH 2.0 and can be done simply. The documentation/manpages can be found [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/basics-of-authentication/).